# vim ~/.ssh/config command isn't showing any results

Tags: vim, git-bash, github-for-windows

I'm using windows 10 ,I want to get into the SSH file but whenever I type **"vim ~/.ssh/config"** into my Git Bash the result I get is this
[image]

**but the result I'm trying to get is supposed to look like the ones are showing in this second picture:**

[image]

Can someone tell me how to get those results in my command ?

Comment: open a new bash terminal, type `cd` then Enter, then type `pwd` then Enter. What is the output ?

Comment: @Niloct that's the output "/c/Users/samoa"

Comment: It looks like you simply don't have a `.ssh/config` file *yet*. You may need to create it from scratch.

Comment: @torek how do i do that ?

Comment: How do you go about creating other files from scratch? What's your normal method? Is there some reason you think that won't work for this case?

Comment: That image shows a *typical* SSH configuration, not any kind of default that you should expect to find on your own machine.

Answer (score 1):

If the second picture is a file you already have on your disk, you need to copy it to your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` folder (since `%USERPROFILE%` is what git bash uses by default as `$HOME` or `~`)

If the second picture is a file you want to have, then you need to create it.